# Git rebase, public remote branches and backing up a work in progress

Tags: git

I'm learning about git rebase and am finding the concept easy to understand if I'm looking at only a local repository, but am finding it difficult to understand when working with a shared remote repository.

Here's are two examples to demonstrate my issue with understanding.

Scenario 1:

I clone a remote repo to my machine. On my machine I:
Create a topic branch off of master 
Do a bunch of commits to the topic branch 
Rebase the commits onto master from my topic branch
Push my changes to remote

Scenario 2:

I clone a remote repo to my machine. On my machine I:
Create a topic branch off of master 
Do a bunch of commits to the topic branch 
Now I have to go home for the day but I don't want my work living on just my machine in case something happens to it. So I push my topic branch to remote.
The next day I return and rebase my commits to master
Push my changes to remote.

If I understand correctly scenario 1 will always work just fine even if I have multiple users that have been using the remote repo and pushing up changes because I'm not messing with any of the existing commits on remote, I'm simply adding to them.

In scenario 2 I want to store my work in progress on remote temporarily, but by doing so I introduce the possibility that one of my teammates might base some of their work off of my remote branch and then once I rebase I might do something to a commit that they are depending on for their work.

Am I correct with my assumptions for scenario 1 and scenario 2?

Is there a safe way to use rebase, cache my changes on remote and not worry about having some conflict later on because a teammate decided to use my remote branch?

Comment: If you use an expression like `push to master`, everybody's brain will shut down immediately, and nobody will be able to answer. `master` is a branch, you usually merge into it. If you want something to push into, it's `origin`, which is a remote. Please enlighten us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Scenario 2, what you would push is usually a branch under your own namespace:

```
git push -o origin topic:neonDion/topic
```

That way, at your next local rebase, you will be able to git push --force that branch without worrying (too much) about your teammates, who are not supposed to base their work from a user branch.

This is however just a convention, and communicating about the policies around those branches in advance is advisable.